# Get files and contents of a directory on a web server via JS

Tags: javascript

I have a directory with an ever-growing list of images, documents (like an FTP), and markdown files.

I was wondering if there was anything in Javascript that would let you point to a directory on a web server, and output a list of the file names.

```js
// example
const directory = '../../files/';

for file in directory {
   console.log( file );
}
```

and then I'd be able to output each file as an item in a list, with a link to the file.

I'd also like to know if there's a way to extract those file's contents if it was something that was simple (a `txt` or `md` file).

Everything I've found is for either nodejs or looking at the filesystem directory.

Comment: JavaScript (from the browser) has no access to the local or server directory

Answer (score 0):

There is no real standard for enumerating the contents of a directory over HTTP.

You'll have to create your own method, server-side.  Or, implement something like WebDAV.